# Which heroes move the fastest along the ground?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2-2017

When one plays the [heroes vs villains](http://battlefront.wikia.com/wiki/Heroes_vs._Villains) games, eventually every player gets selected to be the target for your team.  Often times the best strategy to stay alive when selected is to runaway.  Sure, sometimes working together with your allies is a superior strategy, but other times the team can be scattered through-out the level and the enemy team has joined up.
In that case it makes a lot of sense to just run for it and try to meet up with some allies and help them ambush the pursuers, or just keep running.  The longer you stay alive the more chances your allies will have to attack the enemy target.

**With that said I was wondering which heroes move the fastest?**

Certainly [Boba Fett](http://battlefront.wikia.com/wiki/Boba_Fett/DICE), the only hero with a jet pack, can move the fastest vertically. Though sometimes flying just makes you a more visible target. But I mean along the ground if your just trying to escape.  Also if you know which ones move the slowest that would be nice.

Comment: What does the picture have anything to do with anything?

Comment: Its a picture of the heroes vs villains start, which inspired the question.   Why the hate for pictures?

Comment: [We hate fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luke is the fastest without using dashes or abilities.

Darth Maul is the fastest on the ground when using his spin attack but you were right about Boba Fett being the fastest overall.

These results were from [SammyBoii's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCsH0MfHgXc) where he tested each character's speed empirically. Note that this was timed over a relatively short distance and was posted April 2019.

[image: Freestyle 40 yard dash time (in seconds)]
[image: 40 yard dash time (in seconds)]

Answer (score -2):

I think jedi/sith characters move the fastest. I'm not possitive but I've played the new Battlefront quite a few times and I'm pretty sure jedi/sith move fastest.

Comment: What about Bossck?  He seems fast.

Comment: Again, maybe I'm wrong, but that's what I think. Sorry if I'm incorrect. My answer might also be partially influenced by the original Star Wars Battlefront 2 game (not made by EA) which I play a lot. In that game, jedi/sith characters are the fastest. Again, sorry if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sure, I didn't vote against you for what its worth

Comment: I just asked my friend who plays the EA battlefront 2 all the time and he says he thinks either Kylo Ren, Rey, Bossck, or Maul.